# SwiftUI update child view during transition

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a situation that I have to update a child view within a view that is under an onging transition.

Here is a simple code to reproduce/demonstrate the issue I just mentioned.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
    @State var isOn = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if isOn {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                    Text(text)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            .animation(.default, value: isOn)

            Color.clear
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Button("Click") {
                        isOn.toggle()
                        text = isOn ? "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)" : "Hello, Swift!"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have a `Text` which will be hidden/shown by clicking the bottom button. And update the text to a different value when it shows up next time.

If I click the button quickly, which means the text is updated before the transition finished. Then the text loses the transition and shows up directly at the "final" position.

[image]

**How to updating a child view during transition?** Or there is a limitation on SwiftUI for now?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I want the `Text` still move smoothly by the transition effect. It's ok for me that `Text` has a fade transition to update the text. In my real case, this is inside a bottom sheet like style, so I the the text "moved" along with the sheet even its text is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `.debounce(...)` to add a delay
to the `isOn` within a `ObservableObject`

```
class Dmodel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
    @Published var isOn = true
    
    init() {
        $isOn.debounce(for: .seconds(0.8), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var modl = Dmodel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if modl.isOn {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                    Text(modl.text)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            .animation(.default, value: modl.isOn)

            Color.clear
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Button("Click") {
                        modl.isOn.toggle()
                        modl.text = modl.isOn ? "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)" : "Hello, Swift!"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```